# user32.dll. How do i find textbox?

Tags: c#, winapi, user32

So far I make a window - active, to send text using `SendKeys`, but I want to do it in background using `SendMessage`

```
IntPtr main = FindWindow(null, "Label Code (Scan)");
if (!main.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
    {
      if (SetForegroundWindow(main))
         {
            SendKeys.SendWait(code);
            SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
          }
     }
```

I have tried something like:

```
IntPtr main = FindWindow(null, "Label Code (Scan)");
SendMessage(main, 0x000C, 0, "Hello");
```

But it renames window's title to "Hello". Looks like, I need to find child window, but can't find out about `lpszClass`.

```
public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);
```

[image]

Comment: In Winspector, click and drag where it says "click and drag" and then drag the crosshairs unto the textbox itself. What information do you get then?

Comment: @NineBerry it is shown on an image. 00030BA: CVIRTLVDChild00400000 "Label Code (Scan)"

Comment: Use System.Windows.Automation to do everything: find the window, find the textbox, AND enter the text.

Comment: The other application was created with the GUI framework "LabWindows/CVI" where the contents of the window are completely handled by the framework itself and not by the Windows operating system. The textbox is no real Windows textbox and has therefore no Windows handle. You cannot find or control it via the WinAPI.

Comment: Why don't you use [spy++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460750.aspx)?

Comment: @CodeDreamer if what NineBerry days is true, and the child controls are custom drawn and not true Win32 controls, then window-based tools like Spy++ will be useless, but Automation-based tools like Inspect might work.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, you're right. I didn't know that the conrol is not true win32 controls.

Comment: @NineBerry does LabWindows/CVI provide MSAA or UI Automation providers? Wikipedia says version 6 adds ActiveX support (not sure what that means) and 9.0 adds .net support (bindings?), so I'd be surprised if it didn't do either...

Comment: @andlabs According to [accessibility requirements compliance document](http://www.ni.com/pdf/gsa/en/labwindows-cvi-508-accessibility-requirements-compliance-matrix.pdf), they support assistive technologies, which implies that automation will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The controls in the window are not real Windows Controls. They are drawn and managed by the Window itselt. However, the window may support the Windows Automation framework to allow interacting with the controls.

Use the tool [Inspect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318521(v=vs.85).aspx) to check whether the window supports Windows Automation API.

If it does, use the [classes in `System.Windows.Automation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753388.aspx) with the information you see in the Inspect tool to set the text.